# Combine const char with string into another const char

Tags: arduino, strncpy

I've got two `const char [] PROGMEM` variables that I need to concatenate into another `const char [] PROGMEM`. I'm totally new to C and couldn't understand how to use `strncpy` on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580262/combining-two-const-char-together).

```
const char data_one[] PROGMEM = {0x00,0x01,0x02};
const char data_combined[] PROGMEM = data_one + "{0x03,0x04,0x05}";
```

Comment: Does this code compile? Also do you understand the keyword `const` and its semantics?

Comment: @EdHeal It compiles as part of a [larger script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wi-PWN/Wi-PWN/master/arduino/Wi-PWN/data.h)

Comment: Please supply a some code to prove this

Comment: why C++ in the tags?

Comment: It does not compile

Comment: How about `const char data_one_and_two[] PROGMEM = {0x00,0x01,0x02, 0x03,0x04,0x05}";`? Can you use pointers into that for the purposes where you need the subsets?

Comment: @Yunnosch `data_one[]` contains over 100,000+ characters and due to limited storage space, it can only be declared once.

Comment: Arduino is **not** C! It is not a scripting language either!

Comment: "Full script is 100,000+ characters tried to edit again" - **what???**

Answer (score 1):

Using `memcpy` (or `strcpy` or similar) will not be possible since the destination is constant and read-only. You also cannot use something like you show in your sample code.

The only solution I can think of is also one I really don't recommend, since it will make the code somewhat obfuscated and hard to read and maintain, and that is using pre-processor macros.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with macros, when they are used correctly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik True, but in this case I really don't see any way to use macros without it becoming a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: `#define DATA_ONE ...` and `#define DATA_TWO ...`, then use `DATA_ONE` and `DATA_TWO` in two places, each. Doesn't look like it's particularly difficult to maintain.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Except when you need to modify e.g. `DATA_ONE` without modifying the combined use together with `DATA_TWO`. And a few other similar cases.

Comment: It's obvious to me that the intent is for the combined use to always be consistent.